# python code error?

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv
```

After typing the 2nd line, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: ``sys.argv`` is the command line arguments, if this is the interpreter, it's not going to have three arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` isthe script's command-line arguments. Your error says that the number of variables you're trying to unpack into is more than the number of entries in the tuple, which is 1.

You either aren't passing enough arguments, or you're running the command from the interpreter.

Comment: i'm using a terminal...am i not supposed to use that? should i be using textwrangler? i am a new programmer and would really appreciate your help.

Comment: if you're running it from the terminal, give your script arguments like `python myscript.py a b c`.

Comment: Terminal is fine (that's what I use). You have to pass in some arguments: `python script.py one two three`.

Comment: when i should i type in "python script.py one two three"? after lines "from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv"?

Comment: Are you typing these commands into a Python interpreter (`>>> import sys`), or are you saving it to a text file and then running it via `python`?

Comment: i am typing these commands into a python interpreter, thanks, got my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import argv
a, b, c, d = argv
print "The script is called:", a
print "Your first variable is:", b
print "Your second variable is:", c
print "Your third variable is:", d
```

Save this code as: s.py

Run this file from terminal as follows:
[image]